# Retrieving Deleted Data on postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, data-retrieval

I am going to retrieve data on the original table. How am I going to retrieve the deleted data to the original table ?

Comment: If you've committed the transaction, there's no way of getting back the old data unless a) you have a backup or b) are **very** skillful with a hex editor **and** have been lucky enough for your old records not to have been overwritten!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?:

```
create table ex (a int);
insert into ex (a) values (1),(2),(3);
delete from ex where a > 2 returning *;
```

You can check more about `returning` keyword as well as `output_expression` in the [Postgres Docs.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-delete.html)